# How to compile nodejs project to executable include assets inside

Tags: node.js, express, pkg-config

My project as basic as express starter. assets likes image put into public as root, then, template engine "ejs" into views as root. i succefully to compile to exe. but, the exe need to load assets from external. its not load from inside executable. i tell pkg in json to include file that need to include. i'm using PKG library

```
"bin": "index.js",
pkg: {
  "assets": ["views/*", "public/*"],
  "targets: ["node16-win-x64"],
  "outputPath": "dist"
}
```

index.js

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
const port = 80;
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

function index(req, res) {
    res.render('index')
};

app.get('/', index);

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Run')
})
```